# Python bucle while: ¿Por qué mi código está mal?

Tags: python, while

Sucede que tengo un código que programé, el cual pasa a través de tres funciones. Una de ellas controla el estado de la variable *error*, otra de ellas, es una función que divide entre "4" entre "0" sin controlar la excepción, y la última, es una función que tiene la capacidad de dividir entre 0 y controlar la excepción.
La primera función la creé para ir controlando cómo la variable *error* se iba reescribiendo, y en cierta forma me sirve para entender el estado de ejecución del programa. Acá viene mi problema: tras comprobar que efectivamente la variable *error* se encuentra en *False*, mentalmente doy por hecho de que el siguiente bucle:

```
while error == 0:
divisionControlada()
if error == False:
    break
```

No puede ejecutar nuevamente la función "divisionControlada()" porque la condicion que le da origen al bucle while *error==0*, es falsa.
No obstante, cuando ejecuto el programa, la función controlerror() me indica que error=False, y el bucle a continuación se ejecuta de todos modos una vez más, llega a la sentencia if, y al cumplirse que error=false, se rompe el bucle while.
Acá viene la cuestión: no entiendo por qué la función divisionControlada() se ejecuta dos veces.
PD: Sí, el programa tiene un easter egg, espero no les moleste.

### **CÓDIGO:**

```
import time


error = 0

print("""Puede suceder que una función nos arroje un error
justo antes de que venga una línea esencial para el programa.
""")
print("""Para que eso no suceda, debemos de controlar
las excepciones a través de los comandos "try" y "except".
""")
print("""Sabemos que las divisiones por cero no son posibles. Las mismas puede generar
un error como se verá al final del programa
""")


def errorDivision():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Ahora mismo veremos cómo se genera el error de división por cero")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("El programa va a intentar dividir 4 entre 0")
    num1 = 4
    num2 = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    return num1/num2


def divisionControlada():
    x = int(input("Introduzca el primer número        "))
    print("Numerador", x)

    y = int(input("Introduzca el segundo número       "))
    print("Denominador", y)

    try:
        print(x/y)
        global error
        error = False
        time.sleep(1)
        print(error)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("No es posible dividir entre 0")
        print("Operación fallida. Vuelve a intentarlo.")
        time.sleep(2)


def controlerror():
    if error == 0:
        print("La funcion error es igual a", error)
    elif error != 0:
        print("La variable ERROR es igual a", error)


divisionControlada()
**controlerror()**
time.sleep(1)


x = input("Pulsa una tecla para continuar")
controlerror()

while error == 0:
    divisionControlada()
    if error == False:
        break


def final():
    global x
    x = input("""¿Listo para ver qué sucede con un programa cuando no controlamos un error?
Y/N: """)


final()
if x == "Y" or x == "y":
    errorDivision()
elif x == "N" or x == "n":
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" ")
    print("Adios")
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    contador = 0
    while x != "Y" and "y" and "N" and "n":
        contador += 1
        print("Muy gracioso. Volvé a intentarlo")
        final()
        if contador == 4:
            print("Ah, ¿sos gracioso?")
            time.sleep(1)
            while contador > 0:
                print("Idiota")
```

Comment: Por tu código veo que no llevaras mucho timepo programando. Un consejo que te daría yo sería intentaras volver a hacer el programa ya que lo estas intentando hacer de una manera muy liosa y no se entiende muy bien lo que estas intentando hacer. Otra cosa que te diria que tengas cuidado en los lenguajes de POO con la sentencia "break" pq por algunos programadores no la tienen muy bn vista pq viene de programacion estructurada pero eso es ya otro tema. Estos programadores de los que te hablo en vez de utilizar esa setencia utilizan un while con una condición.

Comment: Tbm queria decirte que tuvieras cuidado con la variable error pq estas tratandola al principio como si fuera de tipo Integer y a la mitad del programa como de tipo boolean, eso no es una buena practica si vuelves a hacer el programa ten en cuenta esto. Por otro lado tampoco intentes usar muchas variables globales que a la larga te complican mas el programa que cualquier otra cosa

Comment: Te recomendaría que si `error` va a ser booleano le pongas `true` al principio ya que para vos es importante que diga `false` mas adelante y no el cero actual. También podrías hacer el cambio y colocar cero para inicializar la variable y 1 cuando es verdadero. Es confuso tener la variable `error` con dos tipo de datos diferente, numérico primero y booleano después.

Comment: @CarlosWindows En cuanto a lo de *"Otra cosa que te diria que tengas cuidado en los lenguajes de POO con la sentencia "break" pq por algunos programadores no la tienen muy bn vista pq viene de programacion estructurada"* -> Es completamente falso... siempre que encuentras lo que necesitas en un bucle es muy buena práctica meter un `break` para evitar que el bucle siga haciendo iteraciones totalmente innecesarias... Lo que no es correcto es *abusar* y poner 10 `break` por todos lados, porque entonces dificulta saber si estás en el bucle aun o no. Pero bien usado es una herramienta más, y útil.

Comment: @CarlosWindows Sí. Llevo dos o tres días desde que escribí mi primer "Hola mundo".

Comment: @AleBuo ¿Puedo escribir una variable que no tenga un valor aún? Como cuando definimos una función y dentro de la definición ponemos "pass".

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por la aclaración. De todas formas no entendí muy bien a qué se refería. Supongo que a ProgramaciónOrientadaAObjetos. pero todavía no llegué ahí. Seguro que en unos días ya esté en eso. Intenté crear una condición y que creara un bucle cuando se cumpla la condición, pero al final se me hizo lío y fui creativo. Ya resolví el bug, gracias a AleBuo:))